# Circular Dependency when using Ninject with AuthorizationFilterAttribute and owin for injecting service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, ninject, actionfilterattribute

I have a web api 2 applicationn using woin for self hosting and ninject for dependency injection.I am trying to inject a dependency in a class extending AuthorizationFilterAttribute . I am not able to get it working with success.

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup {
    // This code configures Web API. The Startup class is specified as a type
    // parameter in the WebApp.Start method.
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder) {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        IKernel kernel = CreateKernel();
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizationFilter(kernel.Get<IAuthenticator>()));
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        appBuilder.UseNinjectMiddleware(() => kernel).UseNinjectWebApi(config);
    }

    private static StandardKernel CreateKernel() {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        kernel.Bind<IAuthenticator>().To<AuthServiceAuthenticator>().InSingletonScope()
                .WithConstructorArgument(new {
                    authServiceUrl = @"http://authservice/"
                });
        return kernel;
    }
}
```

**AuthorizationFilter.cs**

```
class AuthorizationFilter : AuthorizationFilterAttribute {
    private const string AUTH_TOKEN_HEADER_KEY = "Session-Id";

    private IAuthenticator _authenticator;
    public AuthorizationFilter(IAuthenticator authenticator) {
        _authenticator = authenticator;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext filterContext) {
        IEnumerable<string> authToken;
        AuthResponse validateResponse = null;

        if (filterContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues(AUTH_TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, out authToken)) {
            bool isAuthorized = _authenticator.ValidateAuthToken(authToken.First(), out validateResponse);
        }
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

**AuthServiceAuthenticator.cs**

```
class AuthServiceAuthenticator : IAuthenticator {
    private const string VALIDATE_PATH = "validate?value=";
    private const string CLIENT_NAME_HEADER = "X-Client-Name";
    public Uri _authServiceUrl;

    public AuthServiceAuthenticator(Uri authServiceUrl) {
        _authServiceUrl = authServiceUrl;
    }

    private Uri BuildValidateUrl(string authToken) {
        string path = VALIDATE_PATH + authToken;
        return new Uri(_authServiceUrl, path);
    }

    public bool ValidateAuthToken(string authToken, out AuthResponse authResponse) {
        Uri validateUrl = BuildValidateUrl(authToken);

        WebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(validateUrl);

        using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse()) {
            try {
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
                        string responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        authResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthResponse>(responseBody);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                response.Close();
            }
        }

        return authResponse?.Success ?? false;
    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting

```
Error activating Uri using implicit self-binding of Uri
 A cyclical dependency was detected between the constructors of two 
 services.

 Activation path:
  3) Injection of dependency Uri into parameter baseUri of constructor of 
   type Uri
  2) Injection of dependency Uri into parameter authServiceUrl of 
  constructor of type AuthServiceAuthenticator
 1) Request for IAuthenticator
```

Comment: your `.WithConstructorArgument(new {
                    authServiceUrl = @"http://authservice/"
                });` does not seem to work. Have you tried the more simple `.WithConstructorArgument(
                    "authServiceUrl", new Uri (@"http://authservice/"
                ));` ?